# echo prints too many spaces

Tags: bash, unix, posix, dash-shell

I have code with two variables in `echo`. I don't know why it prints spaces before `$NEXT` even though I have just one space in code.

```
NEXT=$(find "${DIR}" -type f -name "*.$ext" | sed "s/.*\/\.//g" | sed "s/.*\///g" |
sed -n '/.*\..*/p' | wc -l)
echo "Files .$ext: $NEXT"

Files .tar:        1
```

Comment: If you want help, you need to supply all of the relevant code.

Comment: Either `$NEXT` contains the spaces, or it's a tab.

Comment: My mistake... Now it should be alright.

Comment: Before $NEXT are spaces.

Comment: You have to show how you create `$NEXT`, or we can't know.

Comment: NEXT=$(find "${DIR}" -type f -name "*.$ext" | sed "s/.*\/\.//g" | sed "s/.*\///g" | sed -n '/.*\..*/p' | wc -l)

Comment: Your comment specifying how `$NEXT` is set needs to be in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `find` expression is not doing what you think it is:

```
NEXT=$(find "${DIR}" -type f -name "*.$ext" | sed "s/.*\/\.//g" | sed "s/.*\///g" |
sed -n '/.*\..*/p' | wc -l)
```

When you *pipe* to `wc -l` you are left with a *Number*. The *format* of the number will depend on your distributions default compile options for `wc`. While generally when information is *piped* or *redirected* to `wc` the value returned should be without any leading whitespace (but there is no guarantee that your install of `wc` will work that way). All you can do it test and see what results, e.g.

```
ls "$HOME" | wc -l
```

If whitespace is returned before the value -- you have found your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the last line is the output, then it seems it is an output of something else than displayed code. When your output looks weird, try putting single quotes around each variable:

```bash
echo "  Average file size .'$ext': '$AEXT'"
```

That way, you will know, if the spaces (or tabs) are coming from the variables themselves or from the script.